# Why use tuples instead of objects?

Tags: c++, tuples

The codebase where I work has an object called Pair where A and B are the types of the first and second values in the Pair.  I find this object to be offensive, because it gets used instead of an object with clearly named members.  So I find this:

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> productIds = blah();
// snip many lines and method calls

void doSomething(Pair<Integer, Integer> id) {
  Integer productId = id.first();
  Integer quantity = id.second();
}
```

Instead of

```
class ProductsOrdered {
  int productId;
  int quantityOrdered;
  // accessor methods, etc
}

List<ProductsOrderded> productsOrdered = blah();
```

Many other uses of the Pair in the codebase are similarly bad-smelling.

I Googled tuples and they seem to be often misunderstood or used in dubious ways.  Is there a convincing argument for or against their use?  I can appreciate not wanting to create huge class hierarchies but are there realistic codebases where the class hierarchy would explode if tuples weren't used?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First of all, a tuple is quick and easy: instead of writing a class for every time you want to put 2 things together, there's a template that does it for you.

Second of all, they're generic. For example, in C++ the std::map uses an std::pair of key and value. Thus ANY pair can be used, instead of having to make some kind of wrapper class with accessor methods for every permutation of two types.

Finally, they're useful for returning multiple values. There's really no reason to make a class specifically for a function's multiple return values, and they shouldn't be treated as one object if they're unrelated.

To be fair, the code you pasted is a bad use of a pair.

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate here, but are there really a lot of cases where you need a method that returns multiple unrelated values? The one scenario I see pretty often is the `TryParse` method for the built-in data types in C#. Here, you need to return a `bool` (whether the parse was successful) and, say, an `int` (the value if the parse was successful). To allow a second return value, the `out` keyword is used. I guess a tuple might be nice here instead, but I'm not sure whether it's better than declaring a type with a `bool` named `ParseSuccessful` and a generic `T` named `Value`.

Comment: @DanThMan: yes, though they're not unrelated. For example, the C++ algorithm `equal_range` returns a pair of iterators. Maps in c++ are equivalent to sets of `pair<key, value>`. There are other cases, but I can't think of them right now.

Comment: DanThMan: Coming from the opposite direction (a language that supports multiple return values), one could ask the same: do you ever need "out" parameters if you've got multiple return values?  You want to *return* 2 things, so why does one look like I'm passing it in?  :-)

Comment: Also, most cases where I see "out" params are instances of "try to do this, if OK then save the result here, else tell me it's no good".  Very often there's a parallel method that throws an exception on failure.  So perhaps the *syntax* of exception catching (in languages like C#/Java) is the real problem here: if the try-catch construct was an expression, would you ever need out params?  I'm not sure I would.  Common Lisp has catch-as-expression (and conditions rather than just exceptions), and while you could do something like out-params, I've never once used that strategy in Lisp.

Comment: I don't understand why we wouldn't use a KeyValuePair here.

Comment: @skaz: First of all, this question did not have a particular language tag, so it can be assumed to be language agnostic. Second, KeyValuePair is essentially a tuple but with a few extra methods.

Comment: You can use Tuples for a lot of things, but the best way to think of them is to return more than value of the same type, and by type I don't mean data type, but the same "thing".  And, it needs to be the same size list.  The text-book example is coordinates..  a POINT structure may be a tuple.  If you want to return a point in a 3D space, a tuple of 3 ints or 3 doubles make sense.   Sure, you can have a struct with x, y and z data members, and if you did that, i don't think anyone would say you're doing anything wrong.  Good luck.

Comment: @devuxer I asked a loosely related question [Why not have Jave methods return a tuple instead of an object reference (or null)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24585677/91933). What do you think of that?

Comment: It's amazing to me how people defend poor programming practices like tuples.  Sure, for a language that doesn't have objects it may be a convenient way to group two things.  But what's so special about the number two?  Why not three, four, five things?  Fixating on two is a myopic view of the problem domain.  On top of that, people want to have a FUNCTION return more than one value.  Anyone stop to think for a moment?  That's not what a FUNCTION is supposed to do.  The way around that is to pass mutable parameters (i.e. by reference).  Honestly and for true, it's not all that difficult.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating a type-safe template class for code reuse.  But it's naive to say this is "so quick and easy because this way I don't have to create a class with all the accessors, etc."  You ARE creating a class, it's just hidden from you by syntactic sugar.  And if you're unaware of that fact in C++ it could lead to several different kinds of difficult to find bugs.  Being explicit with your code generally helps avoid those kinds of bugs.  Obfuscation promotes them.

Answer (score 17):

Tuples are used all the time in Python where they are integrated into the language and very useful (they allow multiple return values for starters).

Sometimes, you really just need to pair things and creating a real, honest to god, class is overkill. One the other hand, using tuples when you should really be using a class is just as bad an idea as the reverse.

Comment: +1 returning multiple values is the big reason for me.  A Pair class is probably a good compromise between returning Object[] or a whole new type.

Answer (score 11):

The code example has a few different smells:

- Reinventing the wheel

There is already a tuple available in the framework; the `KeyValuePair` structure. This is used by the `Dictionary` class to store pairs, but you can use it anywhere it fits. (Not saying that it fits in this case...)

- Making a square wheel

If you have a list of pairs it's better to use the `KeyValuePair` structure than a class with the same purpose, as it results in less memory allocations.

- Hiding the intention

A class with properties clearly shows what the values mean, while a `Pair<int,int>` class doesn't tell you anything about what the values represent (only that they are probably related somehow). To make the code reasonably self explanatory with a list like that you would have to give the list a very desciptive name, like `productIdAndQuantityPairs`...

Answer (score 8):

For what its worth, the code in the OP is a mess not because it uses tuples, but because the values in the tuple are too weakly typed. Compare the following:

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> products_weak = blah1();
List<Pair<Product, Integer>> products_strong = blah2();
```

I'd get upset too if my dev team were passing around IDs rather than class instances around, because an integer can represent *anything*.

---

With that being said, tuples are extremely useful when you use them right:

- Tuples exist to group ad hoc values together. They are certainly better than creating excessive numbers of wrapper classes.
- Useful alternative to out/ref parameters when you need to return more than one value from a function.

However, tuples in C# make my eyes water. Many languages like OCaml, Python, Haskell, F#, and so on have a special, concise syntax for defining tuples. For example, in F#, the [Map module](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/FSharp.Core/Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Map.html) defines a constructor as follows:

```
val of_list : ('key * 'a) list -> Map<'key,'a>
```

I can create an instance of a map using:

```
(* val values : (int * string) list *)
let values = 
    [1, "US";
     2, "Canada";
     3, "UK";
     4, "Australia";
     5, "Slovenia"]

(* val dict : Map<int, string> *)
let dict = Map.of_list values
```

The equilvalent code in C# is ridicuous:

```
var values = new Tuple<int, string>[] {
     new Tuple<int, string>(1, "US"),
     new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Canada"),
     new Tuple<int, string>(3, "UK"),
     new Tuple<int, string>(4, "Australia"),
     new Tuple<int, string>(5, "Slovenia")
     }

 var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(values);
```

I don't believe there is anything wrong with tuples *in principle*, but C#'s syntax is too cumbersome to get the most use out of them.

Comment: You can clean it up a bit though. How about this helper class?
static class Tuple { static Tuple<T0, T1> Build<T0, T1>(T0 t0, T1 t1); }
Then you can create a tuple like so: Tuple.Build(1, "US");
Exploit that generic types are inferred for functions. :)

Comment: Still not as clean as in Python or ML/F#, but at least you avoid having to specify the generic parameters

Comment: Your tuple code here could be done with a dictionary using dictionary initializers. (new Dictionary<int, string>() { {1, "US"} {2, "Canada" } }).ToTuple() ?

Comment: Re: passing around IDs: IDs are actually convenient to pass around, especially when you are going from one tier to another tier.  But in this case you have to reverse engineer the code to figure out that the first integer is an ID.

Answer (score 5):

It's code reuse. Rather than writing Yet Another Class With Exactly The Same Structure As The Last 5 Tuple-Like Classes We Made, you make... a Tuple class, and use that whenever you need a tuple.

If the only significance of the class is "to store a pair of values", then I'd say using tuples is an obvious idea. I'd say it was a code smell (as much as I hate the term) if you started implementing multiple identical classes just so that you could rename the two members.

Answer (score 3):

This is just prototype-quality code that likely was smashed together and has never been refactored.  Not fixing it is just laziness.

The real use for tuples is for generic functionality that really doesn't care what the component parts are, but just operates at the tuple level.

Comment: Exactly what he suggested would work.  Without seeing more context I can't comment really on that.

Answer (score 2):

Many things have already been mentioned, but I think one should also mention, that there are some programming styles, that differ from OOP and for those tuples are quite useful.

Functional programming languages like Haskell for example don't have classes at all.

Answer (score 2):

Scala has tuple-valued types, all the way from 2-tuples (Pairs) up to tuples with 20+ elements.  See [First Steps to Scala](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/steps.html) (step 9):

```
val pair = (99, "Luftballons")
println(pair._1)
println(pair._2)
```

Tuples are useful if you need to bundle together values for some relatively *ad hoc* purpose.  For example, if you have a function that needs to return two fairly unrelated objects, rather than create a new class to hold the two objects, you return a Pair from the function.

I completely agree with other posters that tuples can be misused.  If a tuple has any sort of semantics important to your application, you should use a proper class instead.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious example is a coordinate pair (or triple). The labels are irrelevant; using X and Y (and Z) is just a convention. Making them uniform makes it clear that they can be treated in the same way.

Comment: @JohnGibb - the items in a `Tuple` are expected to have different meanings. This is why you have to specify their types individually: `Item1` can be a string but `Item2` an integer, etc.

Comment: In fact, `x` and `y` actually have symmetry (usually in a coordinate system we treat every dimension identically), and so it would make even more sense to go a step further and put them in an array!

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to sort by a particular key (which is expensive to compute repeatedly), or something like that, a class seems to be a bit overkill:

```
val transformed = data map {x => (x.expensiveOperation, x)}
val sortedTransformed = transformed sort {(x, y) => x._1 < y._1}
val sorted = sortedTransformed map {case (_, x) => x}
```

Having a `class DataAndKey` or whatever seems a bit superfluous here.

Your example was not a good example of a tuple, though, I agree.