# Why use tuples?

Tags: tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use tuples instead of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675237/why-use-tuples-instead-of-objects)

Suppose you are using a programming language that allows you to return multiple values from functions, e.g.,  `x, y = f(a, b)`.

It seems to me like using a struct/object that has named attributes is generally better than using a tuple, for readability.  For example, I think `p.x` is more readable than `p[0]`.

A common use of tuples is for key-value pairs in associative arrays.  But to me, `x.key` and `x.value` seems more clear than `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

Is the reason for tuples instead of named types just convenience?  This makes me think the syntactic overhead for declaring new types is too high in most programming languages.

Comment: I took a look at that post beforehand.  The accepted answer just says 3 things: 1. They are useful for returning multiple values from a function.  Why does the mechanism for returning multiple values have to be different from the way functions take multiple values?  2. They are useful because they can be used for any combination of types.  Have they never heard of parametric polymorphism?  3. They are "quick and easy."  Is the syntactic overhead for creating a new type too high? (I think the answer may be yes in most programming languages!)  By that argument, why not use tuples for everything?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a constructive/definitive answer to the question. I think there are many good alternatives to tuples (c# anonymous types can be an elegant alternative when the type is used within scope and they are arguably syntactically easier to create than a tuple). Personally I rarely use tuples, but they do have their uses when structuring internal data, i.e. not the input of a function, nor the output, but handling data in some intermediate stage.