# Why not have Jave methods return a tuple instead of an object reference (or null)?

Tags: java, methods, null, tuples

Typically Java methods look like:

```
public <U,V> U doSomething(V aReference) {
    // Do something
}
```

This typically means that the method `doSomething()` returns a `null` if it
fails (for whatever reason) or a valid object reference.  In some cases the
"valid object reference" may itself be `null`.  For example, the method
`aMap.get(k)` may return `null` if there is no key `k` or if *there is a key
`k`* but its corresponding value is `null`. Confusion!

Not to mention `NullPointerException`s if 50% of your LOC isn't just
null-checking.

What's wrong with methods looking like this:

```
public <T> ReturnTuple<T> doSomething(V aReference) {
    T anotherObjRef = getValidObjT();
    if (successful) {
        return ReturnTuple.getSuccessTuple(anotherObjRef);
    } else {
        return ReturnTuple.getFailureTuple("aReference can't be null");
    }
}
```

where the class `ReturnTuple<T>` is defined something like:

```
class ReturnTuple<T> {
    private boolean success;

    // Read only if success == true
    private T returnValue;

    // Read only if success == false
    private String failureReason;

    // Private constructors, getters, setters & other convenience methods

    public static <T> ReturnTuple<T> getSuccessTuple(T retVal) {
        // This code is trivial
    }

    public static <T> ReturnTuple<T> getFailureTuple(String failureReason) {
        // This code is trivial
    }
}
```

Then the calling code will look like:

```
ReturnTuple<T> rt = doSomething(v);
if (rt.isSuccess()) {
    // yay!
} else {
    // boo hoo!
}
```

So, my question is: why isn't this pattern more common?  What is wrong with it?

Keep in mind I am not asking for a critique of this exact code, but for a
critique of this general idea.

**Please note:** the point here is not to get the code above to compile, just to
discuss an idea. So please don't be too pedantic about code correctness :-).

### Edit 1: Motivation

I guess I should have added this section from the beginning, but better late
than never...

- Ever wished a method could return two values at once?  Or that the returning
  of a value could be de-linked from the ability to indicate success or
  failure?
- This could also promote the idea of a method being a neat-and-clean
  self-contained unit (low coupling and high cohesion): handle all (or most)
  exceptions generated during it's execution (not talking about exceptions
  like `IllegalArgumentException`), discreetly log failure reasons (rather
  than the ugly stack trace of an uncaught exception) and only bother the
  caller with exactly the information required.  IMHO this also promotes
  information-hiding and encapsulation.
- Done your best with testing, but when the code is deployed to the customer,
  an uncaught exception's ugly stack trace makes it all look so
  unprofessional.
- Similar to the point above: you may have code that could possibly generate
  20 different exceptions but you're catching only 5-7 of those.  As we all
  know, customers do the damndest things: rely on them to cause all the other
  uncaught 13-15 exceptions :-). You end up looking bad when they see a big
  stack trace (instead of a discrete failure reason added to the logs).

  This is the difference (for example) between showing a stack trace to a
  user in a web app vs. showing them a nicely formatted 5xx error page saying
  something like: "There was an error and your request couldn't be completed.
  Admins have been notified and will fix as soon as possible." etc.

This idea isn't entirely without merit as Java 8 provides the
[Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)
class (as pointed out by @JBNizet) and Google's
[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library also has an
[Optional](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained#Optional)
class. This just takes that a little further.

Comment: Why go through so much overhead just to end up with `if(bla.isSuccess())` compared to `if(bla != null)`?

Comment: Because a null return causes confusion: it may not always mean failure, it may be a genuine successful value (see `Map` example above). Plus, the called method can catch exceptions (if preferred) and simply indicate failure along with a failure message.

Comment: And a map can also just call `ContainsKey()`. I don't see your point about the exceptions: how is that influenced by any of this?

Comment: @TAsk it's not a question of overhead, it's a question of being able to a) clearly indicate success or failure and b) in case of failure, simultaneously return a failure reason.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The traditional Java way is to throw and catch exceptions all over the place. Instead each method can be self-contained (promoting low coupling) and simply indicate success or failure. Haven't you seen in your experience code where uncaught exceptions only show up when deployed to the customer? Looks so ugly.

Comment: @TAsk There is only one success or failure, but there might be 20 possible exceptions, many of which will not be checked exceptions, thus there won't be corresponding catch statements... let your imagination fly from there...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html. Not that its intended usage is not exactly what you're asking. If the goal is to signal an invalid argument, you should throw a NullPointerException or an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the link. So I wasn't so far off the mark then! Obviously it's a feature others have wanted if it's going to be part of Java 8. Maybe you could add this as a sort of answer (with some basic commentary)?

Comment: @Task I think the genericized `ReturnTuple<T>` should mean there would be no scalability issues, but only real-world usage can answer that with any reliability...

Answer (score 3):

> This typically means that the method `doSomething()` returns a null if it fails

No, it does not mean that. It means that the method `doSomething()` may sometimes legally return `null`, without a failure. Java provides a powerful system for handling failures - namely, exception handling. This is how the API should indicate failures.

> why isn't this [return a tuple] pattern more common? What is wrong with it?

The primary thing that is wrong with this pattern is that it is using a mechanism of reporting failures in a way that is foreign to Java. If your API runs into a failure, throw an exception. This saves you from creating twice as many objects as needed in "mainstream" cases, and keeps your APIs intuitively understandable to people who learned the Java class library well.

There are situations when returning a `null` can be *interpreted* both ways - as a failure, and as a legitimate return value. Looking up objects in associative containers provide a good example: when you supply a key that is not in the map, one could claim that that is a programming error and throw an exception (.NET class library does that) or claim that when the key is missing, the corresponding spot in the map contains the default value, i.e. a `null` - the way this is done in Java. In situations like that it is entirely acceptable to return a tuple. Java's `Map` decided against this, most likely to save on creating additional objects every time an object is requested from a `Map`.

Comment: That's why I used the word "typically" **and** gave an example where a `null` may be a valid return value :-). You have a bit of a point in "keeps your APIs intuitively understandable to people who learned the Java class library well".